# Is it possible to Blur a VBox in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to blur a VBox component when my mouse is out of it and unblur it when my cursor comes back to the VBox region. How can I blur a VBox in Flex?

Comment: Or is it possible to apply a filter to an HBox or VBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use the following

```
<mx:GlowFilter id="glow" blurX="12" blurY="12" color="#88AEF7" quality="2" strength="1"/>
<mx:BlurFilter id="blur" blurX="4" blurY="4" quality="2" />
<mx:DropShadowFilter id="dropShadow" alpha="0.35" blurX="6" blurY="6" distance="6" color="#000000" angle="90" />
<mx:BevelFilter id="bevel" angle="45" blurX="0.5" blurY="0.5" distance="4" strength="0.7" highlightAlpha="0.7" shadowAlpha="0.7"/>
```

any other component

Comment: <mx:Box filters="{[bevel,glow,blur,dropShadow]}"

Comment: check out this online explorer.... http://merhl.com/flex2_samples/filterExplorer/